# Spring http remote

Tags: spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь удалённо вызвать метод. Запускаю оба сервера на одном компьютере (Tomcat). Но получаю вот такую ошибку:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://localhost:8080/contactExporter]; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Did not receive successful HTTP response: status code = 500, status message = [Internal Server Error]

### Provider

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="contactExporter" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="contactService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.springapp.mvc.Service"/>
</bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>accountExporter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>accountExporter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/contactExporter</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### Client

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="proxyFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/contactExporter"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.springapp.mvc.ClientService"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Не смоли ответить и закрыли! Хм... печально.

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - проблема на стороне вызываемого сервера. Посмотрите его логи, киньте в вопрос стектрейс.